# h:commandLink not working in ui:repeat

Tags: jsf

I want to display details about a product when a user clicks on a link with the name of that product.

When debugging my code I see that the `details` method shown in the code below doesn't run.

My code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/Shared/layout.xhtml" >
        <ui:define name="title">Product</ui:define>
        <ui:define name="body">
            <div id="contents" >
                <h3> List Product in Site </h3>
                <ul>
                    <ui:repeat value="#{productBean.listProduct}" var="p">
                        <div id="list-item">
                            <div class='item' >
                                <div class='item-img' >
                                    <h:form>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="#{p.productId}" />
                                        <h:commandLink action="#{productBean.details}">
                                            <h:graphicImage url="#{p.picture}" alt='No Picture' />
                                        </h:commandLink>
                                    </h:form>
                                </div>
                                <h:form>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="#{p.productId}" />
                                    <h:commandLink value="#{p.name}" action="#{productBean}" >
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </h:form>
                            </div>    
                        </div>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </ul>
                <h:form>
                    <h:commandLink value="text" action="#{productBean.test}">  <!-- test -->
                    </h:commandLink>
                </h:form>
            </div>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

ProductBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ProductBean implements Serializable {

    private List<Products> listProduct;
    private List<Categories> listCategory;
    private Products product;

    public Products getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Products product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public ProductBean() {
        listCategory = new ProductsDB().listCategory();
    }
    private int categoryId;

    public int getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String listProductByCt() {
        try {
            String value = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                    getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("categoryId");
            setCategoryId(Integer.parseInt(value));
            if (categoryId == 0) {
                return "index";
            }
            listProduct = new ProductsDB().listProducts(categoryId);
            return "product";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "error";
        }
    }

    public String details() {
        String s = "";
        try {
            String productId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                    getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("productId");
            if (productId != null) {
                product = new ProductsDB().getProductById(productId);
                return "details";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "error";
        }
        return "error";
    }

    public String test()
    {
        return "s";
    }



    public List<Categories> getListCategory() {
        return listCategory;
    }

    public void setListCategory(List<Categories> listCategory) {
        this.listCategory = listCategory;
    }

    public List<Products> getListProduct() {
        return listProduct;
    }

    public void setListProduct(List<Products> listProduct) {
        this.listProduct = listProduct;
    }
}
```

I've also tried with another method called `test`. This too is referenced from an action on `products.xhtml`, but that action isn't placed inside a `<ui:repeat>`. In this case, the method does gets executed.

The test method:

```
public String test() {
    String productId = "IP16G";
    product = new ProductsDB().getProductById(productId);
    return "details";
}
```

Comment: The second CommandLink doesn't point to a method, but only to a bean. Is that a typo or your actual code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of JSF are you using?

The code you've shown with different forms and hidden inputs inside a `ui:repeat` is not really idiomatic JSF. There's also a typo in the action of your first command link. It says `produtBean` but I guess it should be `productBean`. JSF will give you an exception though if you click on that command link.

Did you got that exception, or did nothing happen?

In case nothing happened, a likely cause is that the data you used to render your command links (`#{productBean.listProduct}`) is not available anymore after the post back. What method are you using to obtain this data and what is the scope of your bean? In many cases you should be using `@ViewScoped` and initialize the data when the request is **not** a post back.

Also, make sure there is no parent component of the `<ui:repeat>` that has a rendered attribute that is set to `false` by default. In case this attribute will be set to `true` at some point of the life-cycle, this may well be -after- the click on the link is processed. If that happens, it will still be `false` when the click is being processed, which has the effect that it will silently be ignored.

You can test the last effect by putting your test command link right next to the `<ui:repeat>`:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{productBean.products}" var="product">
    ...
</ui:repeat>
<h:commandLink value="test" action="#{productBean.test}" />
```

Although your approach with the multiple forms and hidden fields does work, a more idiomatic JSF version would be:

```
<h:form>
    <ui:repeat value="#{productBean.products}" var="product">
        <h:commandLink action="#{productBean.details(product)}">
            <h:graphicImage url="#{product.picture}" alt="No Picture" />
        </h:commandLink>

        <h:commandLink value="#{product.name}" action="#{productBean.details(product)}" />
    </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

With your bean's `details` method as:

```
public String details(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
    return "details";
}
```

*(getting more off-topic, but if all your method does is returning a navigation case, you might want to consider using a direct link like `<h:link>` with the Id of your product as a parameter. This will use GET to go to your destination page, which in this case is much cleaner)*

**EDIT**

In order to test whether the problem isn't somewhere else, try the following code. It's a single page and a single backing bean. Add these to your project and request the page. This should work.

forminloop.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <h:body>

        <ui:repeat value="#{formInLoopBacking.items}" var="item">
            <h:form>
                <h:commandLink value="#{item}" action="#{formInLoopBacking.action}"/>
            </h:form>
        </ui:repeat>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

FormInLoopBacking.java

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class FormInLoopBacking {

    private String[] items = {"A", "B"};

    public String[] getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void action() {
        System.out.println("Action called");
    }

}
```

Comment: @Arijan : i'm using JSF 2.1 . I've also try approach put ui:repeart inside a form, but it don't running . ProductBean is SessionScoped, it also has got a method ( show listProduct by categoryName ) – user1542080 10 mins ago

Comment: So with JSF 2.1, at least you don't have the use the hidden fields and can hand over the item of the current iteration directly to the method. SessionScoped is **WRONG** for this use case (think of what happens if people open multiple tabs), but at least it should preserve the data for now. I think you need to show your entire backing bean. Specifically the parts where you initialize the data for the ui:repeat is important. Additionally, does the `ui:repeat` has any parent tags with a `rendered` attribute?

Comment: listProducts displayed in page. i think that it has got problem in `<ui:repeat>` . i try using commandLink,which not inside `<ui:repeat>` . in this case, it is true .

Comment: @user1542080 Your bean is request scoped, so this means it will try to load all products every time from the "DB" again. In general this is an anti-pattern. If this "DB" is a shared resource, you'll have no guarantee data is the same before and after the post back. Try printing out the number of items in `listProduct` right after it's being loaded in the constructor and check the numbers match when the page is rendered and after you click on it. I'll post some example code for you to try out as well.

Comment: @hoanvd1210 Did you find the core problem now? (Whether to use AJAX is up to you. If you go to a complete new page, just link via GET. If you do inline editing, AJAX is typically the way to go. But this is a topic for a new question. SO doesn't recommend extended discussions in comments ;))

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your above code

you have open `<ui:repeat>` tag but not closed it and try to put whole `<ui:repeat>` inside a form and check on your page is a `<h:form>` tag inside a `h:form`. If its not work then check your bean is in view scope or not if not put in view scope.

Comment: The unclosed `<ui:repeat>` was just a code formatting error. The OP didn't pay carefully attention to code formatting rules and the message preview (as did you initially).

Comment: @user1542080 put your backing bean class in view scope and check it is working or not